# Select all BUT certain index pairs in multi-dimensional array Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I am trying to select all BUT certain index pairs in a multi-dimensional array. i.e. I have a set of paired indices (e.g. [1,2] and [4,5]). I want to set all BUT those indexed pairs to 0.

The closest I have come to this is:

```
A(setdiff(1:length(A(:,1)),lon),setdiff(1:length(A(1,:)),lat)) = 0;
```

, where A is the matrix and lon and lat are the index pairs I want to keep. However, that also leaves all the intersecting rows and columns of those pairs.

Any ideas?

Here is some example code:

```
A = ones([5,5])
A =

     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1

lon = [1];

lat = [4];

A(setdiff(1:length(A(:,1)),lon),setdiff(1:length(A(1,:)),lat)) = 0

A =

     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1     0
```

What I want is:

A =

```
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Can you provide a short bit of example data?

Comment: Is the last piece what you *want* or what you currently get?

Comment: Sorry, no I only want the one index pair, not the whole intersecting rows and columns. Even though you already answered my question, I will update my it to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is actually the opposite of what you have tried. First you want to start with a matrix of zeros and then only fill in those pairs that you have stored in `lat` and `lon`. Also because you have paired subscripts, you will want to convert those to a linear index using `sub2ind`

```
%// Convert subscripts to a linear index
inds = sub2ind(size(A), lon, lat);

%// Start off with a matrix of zeros
B = zeros(size(A));

%// Fill in the values at the specified lat/lon from A
B(inds) = A(inds);
```